# Algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$ but not a normal extension

Tags: galois-theory

Give an example of an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree 3 which is not a normal extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the splitting field of the polynomial $x^3-3x+1$ over $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if an irreducible degree $3$ polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has complex roots and $a$ is the real root, then $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is not normal.